# How do I stop excel updating cell references upon insertion of new data

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet which takes in certain parameters that I update every day. This is then inserted into a separate worksheet which holds all inserted data. I then use this data to take an average of the latest 5 entries to smooth out day to day variation: e.g.

=((B1*(100-(AVERAGE(Data!G$**2**:G$**6**))))/(343.805764))

When I insert a new data line, my formula updates to:

=((B1*(100-(AVERAGE(Data!G$**3**:G$**7**))))/(343.805764))

How can I prevent this update?

Comment: So you insert the new data in a row above the formulas that get changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to "fix" a range - regardless of the default behaviour of Excel to change row-numbers if you insert new rows - try working with hard-coded ranges using **INDEX**

```
=((B1*(100-(AVERAGE(INDEX(Data!G:G,2):INDEX(Data!G:G,6)))))/(343.805764))
```

Comment: Certainly isn't a quick solution and will take time implementing throughout my code, but it does work. Thanks